# ajax file upload - How can i get the result data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file-upload

I have a new file upload

And here is the html for this

```
<div class="fileuploader" name="myfile">upload</div>
```

And the js is

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".fileuploader").each(function(){ 
    $(this).uploadFile(
      {
        url:"prsfileupload",
        allowedTypes:"msg,xls,xlsx",
        fileName:"myfile"
      }
    );
  } );
}, 2000);
```

Once I upload the file the prsfileupload will move the file to the directory, but how can I show the file data that is returned by that function on the success event.

I shall have the load like resultdiv, but how can I show it in the success event.

Something like `$('div#rediv').text(data);` How can i receive from it ?

Here is the js http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/5/ and here is my chop.

Comment: When posting a question on StackOverflow, please format your code.

Comment: start by reading the plugin docs

Comment: read this for better implementation http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: @AnkushJain : Thanks but i can't find how to return the file name on success event